# Selenium FindElements for long paths

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

For elements that have a long, non-unique path I have been doing compound find element queries. For example, `webdriver.findElement(by.className(topclass).findElement(by.xpath(.//div/div/div)).findElement(By.className(item))`

etc etc. One it breaks it up such that if a middle element changes it is a little easier to read and change. It avoids a really long xpath.

I have now come to the problem that i want to return all the children nodes of an element with one of these long, non unique path elements and I want to use the findElements(By) method to do this. The problem with that is the long way that i outlined above returns a webelement which is not the input parameter of findElements(). Is there a way to do this or am I forced to make a long xpath?

```
<div class=topclass>
       <div>
           <div>
              <div>
                <div class=item></div>
              </div>
           </div>
       <div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can create an extension method to webelement to return more than one element. And in my humble opinion, I think the problem is not the long xpath, but the way how you write it. The xpath is usefull because you can get parent elements and compare inner text inside the selector, something that css selector does not allow

Comment: I can't understand your question... can you please describe it better? By the way, the way you locate elements is awful:) 
The path you wrote could be probably rewrited to something like this: by.cssselector(".topclass div > item");

Comment: @StriterAlfa but an xpath is the least maintainable according to selenium best practices that I have found. I also think you can compare text of the cssselector. But anyway i do not think I made my question clear unless your response is i should just make a long xpath.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba i dont think i conveyed what i was trying to do with that long compound find element statement. would your solution work for the layout i added to the question?

Comment: @Kevin it depends on other HTML. Try this: ".topclass div > div.item"

Comment: ".topclass .item" works too in your html. Also you can add the div tag in selector if class "topclass" or "item" is used in other tag that is not div.